# What is the use of xreg in auto.arima function?

Tags: r, time-series, arima

I am working on predicting the number of customer attending an hospital to perform MR scan per day. I have the daily count of the customers attending the hospital for the last 4 years. But I am not able to capture the daily change in the count of customers attending the hospital for different months accurately.

I am working on Rstudio and I have tried `arima` as suggested by Rob Hyndman.

```
modelfitsample<- read.csv("data_xreg_train.csv")
modeltest <- read.csv("data_xreg_test.csv")

ts_beverly_train <- ts(modelfitsample$Volume, start = c(2015,1), frequency=365.25)
ts_beverly_test <- ts(modeltest$Volume, start = c(2018,1), frequency=365)

xreg <- cbind(month=model.matrix(~as.factor(modelfitsample$Month)))
xreg1 <- cbind(month=model.matrix(~as.factor(modeltest$Month)))

modArima <- auto.arima(ts_beverly_train, xreg=xreg)
modArima

fit11 <- forecast(modArima, h=485, xreg = xreg1)

plot(fit11)
```

I need a prediction that can capture the daily change and also consider the monthly seasonality

Comment: Welcome to SO. Prior to asking these questions you should read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), in order to make it easier to help you out, and to not waste time for those who spent their free-time answering questions on SO. For starters this question has **nothing** to do with excel, sas or python, as such these tags should not be included. Also you have no question in your question body.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I will keep this in mind the next time I upload a question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am suprised no one has come up with an answer to this one.

`xreg` in `forecast::auto.arima` and `forecast::Arima` is used for any external regressors. Lets say you want to model `income` over a time period (or over a series of job changes, or wage interviews). It is likely that your income tomorrow, depends on your income today, but it is also likely to depend on your `sex`, `age` and various other factors. These factors may or may not have a time serial part, for example `sex` is in most cases constant.

These parts can be included via the `xreg` argument, specifying the level for each observation in your time series.

Comment: Just wanted to add that including constant features in the xreg argument will throw an error https://github.com/robjhyndman/forecast/issues/699